# SAP HANA filter DATE column with current date / now

Tags: filter, hana

In SAP HANA I can use filters as SQL or Column Store expression within a modelling view (e.g. Calculation View). I chose SQL.

Filter I tried:

```
gueltig_bis >= to_date(now())
```

Which results in an activation error:

```
...  SQL expression '"_BIC_RAGUELTIA" >= to_date(now())' cannot be converted to column store expression: Failed to parse the expression: parsing failed
-> "_BIC_RAGUELTIA" >= to_date(now())  ...
```

However when I use this SQL it executes just fine:

```
select * from "MY_TABLE"
where gueltig_bis >= to_date(now())
```

So what is the correct way to define a filter with the condition:
column gueltig_ab >= <current date>

Answer (score 0):

Use VARCHAR 10 as input parameter with expression `leftstr(string(now()),10)`

[image: Input Parameter Dialog]

Then Use Column Engine in filter expression like this:

[image]